# How to run a single unit test in Django

Tags: django

I run my tests with command "python3 manage.py test" it works fine, but it run all tests. When I try to run test by pushing a button "Run Test"(green triangle) there is an error:

```
Error
ImportError: Failed to import test module: app_shop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djcaching.app_shop'
```

How can I solve this problem?

My structure:

```
djcaching
  app_shop
    tests
  app_users
    tests
  djcaching
    settings
```

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to run single unit test run below command:

```
manage.py test <appname>.tests.<Testcasename>
```

you can also check the official documentation of unit test [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests-1)